# Do I need to install OpenSSH even if it was selected during system installation?

Tags: networking, server, 16.04

Do I need to install OpenSSH on a Ubuntu Server, even thought I marked it during installation of my first Ubuntu server. I am trying to setup a remote desktop client with remmina app on Ubuntu.

Comment: You can always check its installation status with `apt-cache policy openssh-server` or `dpkg -l openssh-server` (replace `openssh-server` with `openssh-client` to check the status of the client package)

Comment: Thanks. I have another question, do I need to install Openssh on the server & client systems? So they can communicate with each other.

Comment: You will need to install the client package on the system you want to connect **from** and the server package on the system you want to connect **to** (although IIRC the server package automatically installs the client package too, as a dependency)